# v-tabs вертикально, Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tabs

Есть такой код:

```
<v-flex md12 class="mt-3">
    <v-tabs
            color="primary"
            dark
    >
        <v-tab @click="getDataPeriod(0)">{{t('All time')}}</v-tab>
        <v-tab @click="getDataPeriod(1)">{{t('Last month')}}</v-tab>
        <v-tab @click="getDataPeriod(2)">{{t('Three month')}}</v-tab>
        <v-tab @click="getDataPeriod(3)">{{t('This year')}}</v-tab>
    </v-tabs>
</v-flex>
```

**Как перевести все tab в вертикальное положение?**

Пробовал добавлять в *v-tabs* атрибут *vertical* - не помогло.

Comment: По документации Vuetify должно с `vertical` работать... Из документации: https://codepen.io/erriourru/pen/popbNYm

Comment: Я знаю, что должно, поэтому не понимаю, что не так))

Comment: Ну не может же оно не работать просто так) Или параметр пишите не туда, или у Вас ошибка какая-то. В консоли что-нибудь выдаёт? Сами вкладки вообще работают?

Comment: Да, вкладки работают как надо, в консоли без ошибок)